# Change gnome panel hiding sensitivity Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel, autohide

I would like to know if there's a way to **change the sensitivity (or response)** of the Gnome panel when the **Autohide** option is enabled, because every time I hover over that area it keeps coming up when I don't really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install gconf-editor and browse to apps/panel/top level. Here you must have things like panel_0, panel_1, top_panel_screen0. Find the ones with autohide checked: these are your panels that you have set to autohide (obviously). Tweak the followning variables to get the desired effect.
auto_hide_size = 0
hide_delay = 300
unhide_delay = 0

Comment: That really did the job, thanks buddy (sorry for the late response).

Comment: You can mark this as answer if this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

The tool you need to install is the compiz config settings manager (sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager). Once installed go to the Unity plugin (use the search box on the upper left) and click on the experimental. The setting you want is the Launcher Reveal Pressure I think.

Comment: I have the ccsm, but I don't see the **Unity** option there. I used the search box but it's not there I think. I don't know if might have something to do but I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, so the Unity option may not appear...
Either way the option is there or isn't I really appreciate your fast response and your help.